# VBA Debugging with breakpoints

Tags: vba, debugging, breakpoints

I need to debug part of a VBA code. 
So I've set a breakpoint in the line I want to start debugging.
But after pressing F8 a few times I want the code to run normally (without having to press F8).

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

alternatively to play you can use F5 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the play button solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the code to run normally you can press **F5** and this will run until complete. However if you want the code to run as normal until a certain point in the code you can insert a breakpoint first by clicking in the margin left of the line you wish the code to break at before pressing **F5**. This is useful if you wish to skip large amounts of code or long loops etc, but still wish to examine a section of code.